# Swift -- Need to click and drag a UIImageView inside a Custom TableView Cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to create a custom TableViewController with a custom UITableViewCell class. I need to be able to drag and drop a photo inside the cell to a panel at the bottom of the view. I have tried a few ways to do this, but I am running into a couple of problems and haven't found a complete solution online:

First of all, after dragging and dropping I would like to return the UIImage view to the cell it came from.

Secondly, I am not able to cast a 'view' to my custom UITableViewClass outside the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' method (so I will have access to the outlets I have set up.)

Here is my relevant code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let thisCell:MealPlanTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mealPlanCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MealPlanTableViewCell

    let meal = mealPlanElementArray[indexPath.row]

    thisCell.postTextLabel.text = meal.2
    thisCell.foodImageView.image = meal.4

    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("wasDragged:"))
    thisCell.foodImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    thisCell.foodImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    return thisCell
}

func wasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if calendarIsUp == calendarIsUp {
        let meal = gesture.view! as! UIImageView
        let sview = gesture.view!.superview!.superview!
        // CAN'T DO THE FOLLOWING -- CAN'T CAST TO CUSTOM CELL
        let mptvc:MealPlanTableViewCell = gesture.view!.superview!.superview! as! MealPlanTableViewCell

        if beginningDrag == true
        {


            beginningDrag = false

            // Move
            meal.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.addSubview(meal)

            beforeDragX = (meal.center.x)
            beforeDragY = (meal.bounds.maxY)

        }
        let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)

        meal.center = CGPoint(x: beforeDragX + translation.x, y: beforeDragY + translation.y)


        if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {

            beginningDrag = true
            // NEED TO ADD BACK TO custom UITableViewCell class.
            sview.addSubview(meal)
            meal.center = CGPoint(x: beforeDragX, y: beforeDragY)

        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 1):

> after dragging and dropping I would like to return the UIImage view to
>   the cell it came from.

- Use the `transform` property to manipulate the position of the
  `foodImageView`.
- When the `UIGestureRecognizer`'s state == `UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended`, instantiate a new `UIImageView` and assign the `foodImageView` image to the new `UIImageView`'s `image` property.
- Add the new `UIImageView` to the desired view.
- Set the `foodImageView`'s transform to `CGAffineTransformIdentity` and animate it.

I'll leave the coding up to you as a learning exercise. For reference, here's a good explanation on CGAffineTransform: [Demystifying CGAffineTransform](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/demystifying-cgaffinetransform.html).

> I am not able to cast a 'view' to my custom UITableViewClass outside
>   the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' method (so I will have access to the
>   outlets I have set up.)

Instead of adding the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the `foodImageView` add it to the custom `UITableViewCell`. Then, in your `wasDragged` function, access the `UIGestureRecognizer.view`, which is the custom `UITableViewCell`, and then access `foodImageView` property. This will eliminate the need to access the `superview` property at all. Accessing the superview property on UI elements in the UIKit framework is never a good idea because Apple can decide to change the structure of the view hierarchy whenever they wish. Ultimately, you are essentially guessing at which view you're going to be using and causing your future self headaches.

**Ex.**

```
func wasDragged(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
{
    if calendarIsUp == calendarIsUp
    {
        let cell = gesture.view! as! MealPlanTableViewCell

        if beginningDrag
        {
            beginningDrag = false

            beforeDragX = cell.foodImageView.center.x
            beforeDragY = cell.foodImageView.bounds.maxY

            // Move
            /*
                I have no idea what view this is so I don't know what to change it to.
            */
            cell.foodImageView.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview?.addSubview(cell.foodImageView)
        }

        let translation = gesture.translationInView(self.view)
        cell.foodImageView.center = CGPoint(x: beforeDragX + translation.x, y: beforeDragY + translation.y)

        if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended
        {
            beginningDrag = true
            // NEED TO ADD BACK TO custom UITableViewCell class.
            cell.contentView.addSubview(cell.foodImageView)
            cell.foodImageView.center = CGPoint(x: beforeDragX, y: beforeDragY)

        }
    }
}
```